# Can I use `expect.stringContaining()` inside a Jest `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` block?

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

Is it possible to use `expect.stringContaining()` inside a Jest `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` block?

I am currently using:

```
expect(createChatRoomMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  creatorId: expect.stringContaining("user_"),
  chatRoomUuid: expect.stringContaining("chatRoom_"),
});
```

But this fails with:

```
    - Expected
    + Received


    Object {
  -   "chatRoomUuid": StringContaining "chatRoom_",
  -   "creatorId": StringContaining "user_",
  +   "chatRoomUuid": "chatRoom_sZ9nj4hC46e4bGz4PjYzpC",
  +   "creatorId": "user_nCQsasvYirUwwoEr3j8HsC",
    },
```

This is odd, as you can see from the error, the recieved strings match what's expected

I've also tried:

```
expect(createChatRoomMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
  creatorId: expect.stringMatching(/user_.*/),
  chatRoomUuid: expect.stringMatching(/chatRoom_.*/),
});
```

With the same results as shown above.

**How can I use `expect.stringContaining()` inside a Jest `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` block?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [bug in jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9937). If there is anything else failing in the test, [Jest will show these as failures, even though they would pass](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9937), for example:

```
  it.only("Test", () => {
    var createChatRoomMock = jest.fn();

    createChatRoomMock({
        "chatRoomUuid": "chatRoom_sZ9nj4hC46e4bGz4PjYzpC",
        "creatorId": "user_nCQsasvYirUwwoEr3j8HsC",
        "somethingElse": "bad"
    });

    expect(createChatRoomMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      creatorId: expect.stringContaining("user_"),
      chatRoomUuid: expect.stringContaining("chatRoom_"),
      somethingElse: expect.stringContaining("good")
    });
  });
```

Will (inaccurately) show that the other `.toHaveBeenCalledWith()` have failed:

```
    - Expected
    + Received

      Object {
    -   "chatRoomUuid": StringContaining "chatRoom_",
    -   "creatorId": StringContaining "user_",
    -   "somethingElse": StringContaining "good",
    +   "chatRoomUuid": "chatRoom_sZ9nj4hC46e4bGz4PjYzpC",
    +   "creatorId": "user_nCQsasvYirUwwoEr3j8HsC",
    +   "somethingElse": "bad",
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be possible.  I wrote the following test and it passed:

```js
test("Test", () => {
    var createChatRoomMock = jest.fn();

    createChatRoomMock({
        "chatRoomUuid": "chatRoom_sZ9nj4hC46e4bGz4PjYzpC",
        "creatorId": "user_nCQsasvYirUwwoEr3j8HsC"
    });

    expect(createChatRoomMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      creatorId: expect.stringContaining("user_"),
      chatRoomUuid: expect.stringContaining("chatRoom_"),
   });
});
```

The only things I could suggest are:

- Check for hidden characters such as Unicode zero-width spaces in the output,
- If you're not using the latest version of Jest, try updating.  I'm using version 25.5.2, the latest available at the time of writing.

Comment: I can second that it is supported and it works. just wrote a similar one and the test passes for me too.

Comment: Thanks Luke and Shamanth! Knowing you couldn't reproduce it was key to finding out the issue - it turns out Jest will report everything as wrong when only one key in expected. I've filed a bug in Jest, and added more detail about it to the answer above. Thanks again!

Comment: @mikemaccana: I'm glad you've found the solution to your problem.  However, please don't make a substantial edit to my answer by adding your solution to it.  Instead, please post your own answer with the solution.

Comment: Hi @lukewoodward! I wanted to add the relevant part that fixes the issue to your answer because I wanted to give you the points. Are you totally sure you would prefer me to add this to a separate answer and accept that new answer instead?

Comment: @mikemaccana: yes, I am totally sure about that, for the simple reason that I didn't write the part you added.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem, but the solution is quite simple:

```
expect(createChatRoomMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  expect.objectContaining({
    creatorId: expect.stringContaining("user_"),
    chatRoomUuid: expect.stringContaining("chatRoom_"),
  })
);
```